# Comment traduire le « disinformation researcher » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, travail

Je [lis](https://www.concordia.ca/cuevents/offices/advancement/2022/05/10/media-manipulation-disinformation-and-misinformation-in-the-digital-age.html) qu'une personne est un/une « [disinformation](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17017257/desinformation) researcher ». Sur la même page je lis qu'une autre personne est « a leading expert on online disinformation, fake news, and digital investigations ». J'en déduis donc qu'il semble y avoir une nuance entre ces titres.

- Le/la « disinformation researcher », est-ce un/ne « [chercheur/chercheuse](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8352050/chercheur) en/sur/dans » ou [autrement](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8399630/recherchiste) ?
- A-t-on besoin d'un autre terme entre le nom et la préposition ?
- Et s'agit-il de *désinformation* ou de *mésinformation* ?

Answer (score 1):

"En" ne me parait pas la bonne préposition, on est chercheur en/dans un champ scientifique, pas dans l'activité condamnable qu'il étudie.

Sur le modèle de "chercheur spécialiste des medias/des réseaux sociaux, etc." je dirais

> Chercheuse spécialiste de la désinformation

Comment: Penses-tu la même chose avec un contexte comme « disinformation researcher with [nom d'une ONG/équipe avec un mandat plus vaste que la désinformation] » ou un CTO dont la biographie sommaire indique qu'il est un « disinformation researcher » mais qui n'a pas d'études spécifiques associées ? Ou disons un cas d'un journaliste qui est présenté encore avec ce vocable dans le contexte très pointu d'une donnée observée sur le terrain ? Penses-tu que dans certains cas on tend vers « personne qui identifie dans le cadre de... » et est-ce que selon toi ça colle avec « chercheur » ou autrement ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'un journaliste voire même un CTO puissent être qualifiés de *researcher*, d'ailleurs l'article fait bien la différence. "Chercheuse spécialiste de la désinformation [à l'université de X] / [chez Y]" me parait correct. On pourrait à la limite ajouter "chercheuse *en sciences de la communication/...* spécialiste de..." pour donner sa discipline au sens plus large.